# Replace \n with <br /> in bash

Tags: string, bash, replace, line-breaks

[UPDATED QUESTION]

I've got a variable `$CHANGED` which stores the output of a subversion command like this: `CHANGED="$(svnlook changed -r $REV $REPOS)"`.

Executing `svnlook changed -r $REV $REPOS` will output the following to the command line:

```
A /path/to/file
A /path/to/file2
A /path/to/file3
```

However, I need to store the output formatted as shown below in a variable `$FILES`:

```
A /path/to/file<br />A /path/to/file2<br />A /path/to/file3<br />
```

I need this for using `$FILES` in a command which generates an email massage like this:

```
sendemail [some-options] $FILES
```

It should to replace `$FILES` with `A /path/to/file<br />A /path/to/file2<br />A /path/to/file3<br />` so that it can interpret the html break tags.

Answer (score 14):

In bash:

```
echo "${VAR//$'\n'/<br />}"
```

See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: thanks, how do I store that output in an other variable? I need to call this variable in a program called "sendemail". I need to call it like this: `sendemail $VAR` . Sendemail understands html, so I need one way to pass those line breaks into it.

Comment: This command does not work. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: It should be `FILES="${VAR//$'\n'/<br />}"`

Comment: Works for me. Looks like you did an error copy/pasting the command. `FILES="${VAR//$'\n'/<br />}"`. Following your edit, replace `VAR` by `CHANGED`

Comment: PS: I've tested the command with the data you posted in the question. If it does not work for, then you posted the wrong information in your question.

Comment: I noticed my mistake: The variable itself does not contain a new line. Or at least it does not show up when I do `echo $CHANGED`, it only shows up when I do `echo "$CHANGED"`. I updated the question.

Comment: That's because the shell will perform word splitting if the variable isn't quoted. If the newlines appear when you quote the variable, then the variable *does* contain the newlines.

Comment: Thanks for all the support. I ended up redirecting my echo output into a file and attaching this file to the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [hek2mgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145467/3744681) to strip out the first `<br />` (if any):

```
CHANGED="
A /path/to/file
A /path/to/other/file
A /path/to/new/file
"

FILES="$(echo "${CHANGED//$'\n'/<br />}" | sed 's#^<br />##g')"

echo "$FILES"
```

Output:

```
A /path/to/file<br />A /path/to/other/file<br />A /path/to/new/file<br />
```

---

Another way (with only `sed`):

```
FILES="$(echo "$CHANGED" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s#\n#<br />#g;s#^<br />##g')"
```

Comment: did not work. echo "$FILES" gives me one single line without anything.

Comment: @WalterBeiter : I think you are doing something wrong, check the variables for misspelling. For convenience, I am updating my comment, copy paste the exact content to terminal and hit enter.

Comment: This combination of bash parameter expansion and `sed` is a) ineffecient, ugly and b) not necessary here. Not, neccesarry because there is no newline at the beginning of the `$CHANGED` and the `<br />` at the end is desired. If it should be necessary then use one tool instead of doing 50% with tool a and 50 % with tool b

Comment: @hek2mgl : Handling newline with `sed` is a bit tricky. It's more readable and understandable this way. If you want proof, try teaching someone how to handle newline with sed and record the time it takes (wink).

Comment: Following the question and the desired output it would be `sed 's/\n/<br \/>/' <<< "$CHANGED"` here. I just wanted to avoid running a extra tool here because bash supports this with parameter expansion.

Comment: Update: The line breaks only appear when I do echo "$CHANGED", they won't show up when I do echo $CHANGED. I think that is the problem

Comment: @hek2mgl : `sed 's/\n/<br \/>/'` ??? huh, huh (LOL) only if life was that easy !!!

Comment: @WalterBeiter Does your input comes from Windows?

Comment: @Jahid You are right, was mixing something. Than I would use `awk ' {$1=$1}1' ORS='<br />'`. The point is, use one tool and use it efficient. But **again**, your output does not match the desired output. Your `sed` command is simply not necessary (or even unwanted)

Comment: No windows, i updated the question, I had wrong information first, sorry.

Comment: @hek2mgl : yes, like I said, it's tricky with `sed`. But I do agree with you that it's not necessary here.

Comment: With `sed` it isn't really tricky, but it requires to load the whole file into memory: `sed 'N;$s/\n/<br />/g'`. Ok that wouldn't remove the last `\n`. To achieve that, I would use `awk` as shown above.

Comment: @hek2mgl : wrong again. May be you were referring to this: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/<br \/>/g'` ... Now, if that isn't tricky I don't know what is..

Comment: My bad. Looks like I was getting a bit rusty at `sed`. Why? Because I almost always use `awk` nowadays. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section of the man page is your friend.

Starting with

```
changed="
A /path/to/file
A /path/to/other/file
A /path/to/new/file
"
```

You can remove leading and trailing newlines using the `#` and `%` expansions:

```
files="${changed#$'\n'}"
files="${files%$'\n'}"
```

Then replace the other newlines with `<br />`:

```
files="${files//$'\n'/<br />}"
```

Demonstration:

```
printf '***%s***\n' "$files"
```

```
***A /path/to/file<br />A /path/to/other/file<br />A /path/to/new/file***
```

(Note that I've changed your all-uppercase variable names to lower case.  Avoid uppercase names for your locals, as these tend to be used for communication via the environment.)

---

If you dislike writing newline as `$'\n'`, you may of course store it in a variable:

```
nl=$'\n'
files="${changed#$nl}"
files="${files%$nl}"
files="${files//$nl/<br />}"
```